# How do I install a CA SSL certificate into a ubuntu server and setup Apache to use it?

Tags: apache-http-server

I was given 3 crt files from my CA issuer. I've done a lot of googling o.O but cannot find where to put these files.

I think they go in /etc/apache2/ssl

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

By convention the certificates should go in /etc/ssl/certs/
The key files should go in /etc/ssl/private/

But it is completely configurable.

For a default site, read the comments in the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

It provides plenty of examples from which you can make your decision.

Answer (score 0):

They go wherever your `ssl.conf` file (most likely) says they go. It completely depends on the distribution. Your distribution might even configure Apache's SSL features in the `httpd.conf` file. On Redhat-derived distributions, it's usually `/etc/pki/tls`.